# SSIS Copying table from 1 server to another

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have been tasked with moving about 500+ tables from one server to another. The servers have the same tables and the tables have the same schema. The issue is that some tables have a read-only column, so I can't just import and dump. In addition, the servers are not linked and the company has a no-linking policy.

This is where I stand:
I have a table name stored in a table in my source server/database. I have an Execute SQL Task to that passes each table name to a Foreach Loop Container. My thought is to write a script, but this is where I am scratching my head. I do not know what the next step would be. Can someone point me in the right direction?
Edit: 
This is my graphical representation.

[image]

Comment: How much data, can you script it to file?  Would backup and restore also be an option?

Comment: We need to fill these tables daily. We can't do a back up because of limitations of the application ( this need to be reconfigured) so I am looking at ssis.

Comment: SqlBulkCopy will do what you want with SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity option.

Comment: Is SqlBulkCopy something i can do in SSIS script?

Comment: Within an Execute SQL task, `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF;` will get you there, if you're just fighting with `IDENTITY` columns.

Comment: i am fighting a timestamp column

Comment: "My thought is to write a script"   A script that does what?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) has Schema and Data comparison and synchronization tools. There are also third party tools available.

[image]

Comment: Can that be used when the databases are on servers that can't be linked?